# Can't display Base64 as PNG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

I have been using the HTML canvas to save a drawing. However, when I try and implement the image using the base64 code it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code I use for my canvas paint (sorry its a bit messy): http://jsfiddle.net/9ht4N/

Here is the code I'm using to display the image: http://jsfiddle.net/QEmcw/
I'm just using something like:

```
<img src="base64 code here" alt="img" />
```

Comment: can you test without the "=" at the end of the base64 code http://jsfiddle.net/QEmcw/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding - it just shows a white image now?

Comment: No a transparent image :S but the image has the good dimension 400x400px. Is it possible that your code doesn't generate good base64 code?

Comment: Possibily its my code not generating the base64 properly then :(

Comment: That works !!! but I don't now yet what code I must change...

Comment: If I console.log the data-URI from your first example and use it an in `img` tag, it works (here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/PNEX4/), so the question arises how you got the data for your second jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

you need this in front of the Base64 Code: "data:image/png;base64,"